# Having two FTP ports for the user

Tags: ftp

I'm running vsftpd on RedHat 6.4 using TLS/SSL on port 990. It works great. I have been tasked to have my VSFTPD server running on unencrypted port 21 as well. This gives my users to either use clear text FTP on port 21 or TLS/SSL on port 990.

I have tried the following in my vsftpd.conf file and did not work.

```
listen_port=990  
listen_port=21
```

In my config file it has the following SSL parameters:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

Can VSFTPD run on port 21 and 990?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  If you need a different configuration for each port (which you do in this case) you'll have to run two separate vsftpd instances with different config files however.